# Написать функцию, которая возвращает полупростые числа до указанного лимита

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Планировала найти сразу простые числа, но не работает моя функция, как написать код?

```
def semiprime_num(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        found = 0 
        for j in range(1,n):  
        if i%j==0:
            found +=1 
    if found==2 or i==1:
            return i

int(input("Input limit: "))
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что форматирование в Питоне не для красоты. Цикл `for j` разве независим от предыдущего?

Comment: Да, при копировании сместила его. Исправлено.

Comment: Вы сами писали этот код? Для чего предназначена функция? Что она, по-вашему, делает (по шагам)?

Comment: Выводит простые числа до указанного предела.По шагам:  
for i in range(1,n): # проход по диапазону от 1 до н
    found = 0 # переменная счётчик 
    for j in range(1,n): # проход по диапазону делителей 
        if i%j==0: # условие: остаток от деления = 0
            found +=1 # увеличиваем значение счетчика
    if found==2 or i==1: # если кол-во совпадений = 2 (делится на 1 и на себя) либо равно 1

Comment: Ну-у-у, ладно (oтступы все равно неправильные.). Но почему "semiprime"?

Comment: Операторы я прочитать могу, но хочется, чтобы Вы задумались над логикой. Например, как функция может вывести чИсла, если она выполняет return одного числА

Comment: Так нужно найти полупростые числа до указанного предела. Как правильно модифицировать мое "творение", чтоб вес работало, как надо?

Comment: Значит добавить нужно список, куда будут числа помещаться.

Comment: Для начала - выяснить, что такое "полупростые числа".

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, если думаете, что я не выяснила этот момент.

Comment: Я могу думать что угодно, в коде это Ваше знание никак не отражено.

Comment: Так в этом и вопрос - я не знаю, как в коде его отразить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лобовой метод - для каждого числа из заданного диапазона производим факторизацию - разложение на простые множители - и подсчитываем их

```
def factors(k):
    cnt = 0
    d = 2
    while d * d <= k:
        while (k % d == 0):
            k //= d
            cnt += 1
        d += 1
    if k > 1:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt

def semiprimes(n):
   return [i for i in range(2, n + 1) if factors(i)==2]

print(semiprimes(100))
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ.